# $Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{H},\mathbb{H})\simeq\mathbb{C}(2)$

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions, spin-geometry

I'm studying the book "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelson. In the proof of proposition 4.2 they say (with no proof) that there is this algebra isomorphism

$$Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{H},\mathbb{H})\simeq\mathbb{C}(2)$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ are quaternions and $\mathbb{C(2)}$ are 2 by 2 complex matrices. 
I can't find anywhere a proof of this fact, can you help me?

Comment: The Hom on the LHS is just linear maps, so we're just thinking of $\mathbb{H}$ as a $2$-dimensional complex vector space here (using any embedding $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{H}$).

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a 2-dim vector space over $\Bbb R$ and
$$
\operatorname {Hom}_{\Bbb R}(\Bbb C,\Bbb C)
$$
is isomorphic to...?

Then observe that $\Bbb H$ is a 2-dim vector space over $\Bbb C$, so, exactly as bofeore...

Comment: $\Bbb{H}=\Bbb{C}\oplus j\Bbb{C}$?